# How to read geopackage tiles using Geotools

Tags: tiles, geotools, dimensions, geopackage

I want to read tiles from a geopackage file using Geotools (v. 17.0). I found the class [GeoPackageReaderTest.java](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/06e864481205da8af17a7e5083c7894d484785fa/modules/plugin/geopkg/src/test/java/org/geotools/geopkg/mosaic/GeoPackageReaderTest.java) on GitHub and modified the example to read tiles from my file:

```
// try to read geopackage tiles (modified from https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/06e864481205da8af17a7e5083c7894d484785fa/modules/plugin/geopkg/src/test/java/org/geotools/geopkg/mosaic/GeoPackageReaderTest.java)
GeoPackage geoPackage = new GeoPackage(inputFile); // inputfile: http://ngageoint.github.io/GeoPackage/examples/rivers.gpkg
GeoPackageReader reader = new GeoPackageReader(inputFile, null);
GeneralParameterValue[] parameters = new GeneralParameterValue[1];
TileEntry tileEntry = geoPackage.tiles().get(0);
ReferencedEnvelope referencedEnvelope = tileEntry.getBounds();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((int) referencedEnvelope.getWidth(), (int) referencedEnvelope.getHeight());
GridEnvelope2D gridEnvelope = new GridEnvelope2D(rectangle);
GridGeometry2D gridGeometry = new GridGeometry2D(gridEnvelope, referencedEnvelope);
parameters[0] = new Parameter<GridGeometry2D>(AbstractGridFormat.READ_GRIDGEOMETRY2D, gridGeometry);
String tableName = tileEntry.getTableName(); // "rivers_tiles"
GridCoverage2D gridCoverage = reader.read(tableName, parameters); // throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Envelope must be at least two-dimensional and non-empty.
RenderedImage img = gridCoverage.getRenderedImage();
```

In the line `reader.read(...)` I get an IllegalArgumentException:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Envelope must be at least
>   two-dimensional and non-empty.

If I am printing the width and height of my envelope I get this result:

```
System.out.println("2 dimensions of gridEnvelope - width: " + gridEnvelope.getWidth() + " | height:" + gridEnvelope.getHeight());
// -> 2 dimensions of gridEnvelope - width: 4.0075016E7 | height:4.0075016E7
```

Any suggestions what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that GeoTools thinks that your [packages coordinate system is infinitely wide and high](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/geopkg/src/main/java/org/geotools/geopkg/mosaic/GeoPackageReader.java#L209) which throws off some of the later calculations and leads to a bounding box which is NaN by NaN and hence the error.

I suspect that this is a bug so if you could [file one](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/) including this test case and the geopackage, some one will look at it.

**Update:** the problem is resolved in newer GT versions (at least >=19.2)! (https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5752)

Comment: Rivers.gpkg opens fine with QGIS. GDAL gives a warning but does not have real problems `Warning 1: Database relies on the 'nga_feature_tile_link' (http://ngageoint.github.io/GeoPackage/docs/extensions/feature-tile-link.html) extension that should be implemented in order to read it safely, but is not currently. Some data may be missing while reading that database.`

Comment: I added the issue: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5752

Comment: This gpkg does not totally fit inside the valid bounds of EPSG:3857 `Upper Left  (-20037508.343,20037508.343) Lower Right (20037508.343,-20037508.343)` which might make trouble. Compare http://epsg.io/3857 `Projected bounds: -20026376.39 -20048966.10 20026376.39 20048966.10`

Comment: If this was the problem the error should be resolved by this line: `GridGeometry2D gridGeometry = new GridGeometry2D(new GridEnvelope2D(new Rectangle(1000,500)), new ReferencedEnvelope(0, 160, 0, 80, referencedEnvelope.getCoordinateReferenceSystem()));`? But the error is the same...

Comment: No, it is reading the CRS from the geopackage which is epsg;3758, look at the code line I mentioned

Comment: Yes, you are right. `worldspan` is `Infinity` with CRS set to `EPSG:3857`. But if I set the EPSG to 4326 the worldspan is 360 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in placing the tileorigin into bottom-left while it should be in top-left that was originally reported by GDAL developer

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Feedback-on-GeoPackage-plugin-td5177340.html

and next faulty noticed by GeoServer developer as a GDAL bug

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6871

which finally lead to fixes in both GeoServer and GeoTools

https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8112

https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5715

Fix seems to be in GeoTools v.1.17.1 but not in v.1.17.0. Update and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but setting the geotools version to 17.1 did not fix the issue.

Comment: If you could made it to open it would have opened in a wrong way with 17.0 so at least you should now have a good version for your tests.